# How to select sibling element with React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

***React Component***

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './CounterButton.css';

const CounterButton = (props)=>{
  
    const [currentCount, setCurrentCount] = useState(0);
    
    const handleClick = (event)=>{
        if(currentCount == 9){
            event.target.classList.toggle('bound-hit');
        }
        setCurrentCount(currentCount+props.incrementVal); 
        
    };

    return (
        <div class="count-container">
            <button onClick={handleClick}>+{props.incrementVal}</button>
            <p>{currentCount}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CounterButton;
```

***External stylesheet for this component***

```
.count-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.count-container > button {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.bound-hit {
  color: red;
}
```

I have a react component and stylesheet for that component. In this case it toggle class `bound-hit` to the classList of button. I could select button using `event.target` and but I want to toggle this class to the `<p></p>` tag inside my div. My question is how can I select that p tag using event. p tag is like a sibling of button. div with class `count-container` is parent. I can also select parent div by `event.target.parent` but I want to select p tag and toggle class `bound-hit` to that.. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need a React specific answer here.

In **vanilla JS** you can use the [`nextElementSibling` method](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling).

```js
const handleClick = (event) => {
  const p = event.target.nextElementSibling
}
```

Or instead you can do it **in CSS** with the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

```css
.bound-hit + p {
  // apply styles to the <p> that's just after .bound-hit in the DOM
}
```

---

However, if you "manually" add a class in a react component (meaning that this class gets added to the DOM without any representation in the state), some [virtual DOM reconciliations](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) might end up removing it.

In a lot of cases, this won't be a problem, but if it is, then you should use a state for it. Here's a simplified example of what that would look like:

```
const [pClass, setPClass] = useState('')
const handleClick = () => {
  setPClass('bound-hit')
}

return (
  <p className={pClass} />
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The question shouldn't be "how to select a sibling" but "how to assign CSS class to the P element on [condition]".

If a React component directly has ownership over the (child) elements you can simple change the components state and apply it to the class list of the element using `className`.

Doing any DOM manipulation/traversing within a component is mainly bad form using React and overcomplicates the solution.

```
const CounterButton = (props)=>{
  
    const [currentCount, setCurrentCount] = useState(0);
    const [currentClass, setCurrentClass] = useState();
    
    const handleClick = (event)=>{
        if(currentCount == 9){
            setCurrentClass('bound-hit');
        }
        setCurrentCount(currentCount+props.incrementVal); 
    };

    return (
        <div class="count-container">
            <button onClick={handleClick}>+{props.incrementVal}</button>
            <p className={currentClass}>{currentCount}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: This is correct. In this case you can implement the application logic using a controlled component, and use the useState hook to trigger React to re-render the component when the state is updated. If you really need to manipulate the DOM, then you should make use of the useRef hook to create a ref object and then assign it to the ref attribute of the DOM element you want to modify in your event handler function. See [React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref) for more details about using useRef.